# Using Response in the same PHP file

Tags: php, xml, pattern-matching

I have a one single PHP file in which

first part: Server generates some output.

Second Part:uses the server generated output and submits the information.

what i have done:

File Name: abc.php

```
<?php
//first part
based on the information here server generates some output say:
111 success: id:104.123/12345678 |value:10000045

//second part
i will be using the output generated in the first part.
what i have done is something like this
$server_said = file_get_contents('http://http://abc.php');
//abc.php is the file name
if (preg_match_all('/104.123\:(\d*)/', $server_said, $matches))
//i want to display only 104.123/12345678 part  
{
$input = $matches[1];
} 
$xmlfile = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<identifier identifierType="id">'.$input.'</identifier>'; 

?>
```

error: the intended result is not being displayed at $input, it is just staying as $input

How can i do that?

I am not sure about the code  what i have written above might be wrong.

Comment: where are you trying to submit the information to?

Comment: @3emad .. it is a server which acknowledges with an id ..this id should be embedded in the XML file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regular expression fails, the correct one is:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+\/\d+/', $server_said, $matches))
```

as well, when your output XML, u need to change your headers to what follows:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Comment: preg_match_all('/104.123\d+\.\d+\/\d+/', $server_said, $matches)...i did try something like this for no luck ...there's no value being displayed in $input ...i think there is some error in my approach...

Comment: I have already tested the regular expression i wrote and it works from the example you have given, I'd like to see the actual code, can you paste on pastebin.com

Comment: "<identifier identifierType="DOI">'.input. '</identifier>"
your missing the $ in "input"

Comment: hey thank you for pointing out the error ..but if u run it, the $input displays the all the values in the file ..

Comment: here is the correct regular expression with correct code: if (preg_match_all('/[\d|\w]+\.[\d|\w]+\/[\d|\w]+/', $server_said, $matches)){ $input = $matches[0][0];  } // $matches[0][1] should be the second match